# Multiple Response Headers with the same name in Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

In Java, is it possible to view multiple response headers on a HttpURLConnection if they have the same name?

In the [Oracle documentation for "GetHeaderField"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), it states:

> If called on a connection that sets the same header multiple times
>   with possibly different values, only the last value is returned.

My question is, how do I view all the different values for a header that is set multiple times?

Comment: Not sure but you can try with [`URLConnection#getHeaderFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields())

Comment: Is using something other than URLConnection an option? like https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Answer (score 3):

Use [getHeaderFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields%28%29)

```
List<String> values = conn.getHeaderFields().get("X-Header-Of-Interest");
```

Complete example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class UrlConnectionTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.getContent(); // Force request
        System.out.println(conn.getHeaderFields().get("X-Funky-Header"));
    }
}
```

On Linux you can create a simple single-request server with netcat for testing

```
$ echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nX-Funky-Header: value1\r\nX-Funky-Header: value2\r\n\r\nContent' | nc -l 8888 &
```

Comment: I tried it, still don't seem to be able to get multiple values if the same header is set twice

Comment: With java 1.6.0_13 on Linux it works like a charm.
Are you sure the server is sending multiple headers.